# Missing dates on Min() while using Over and Partition by in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, over-clause

I am using OVER, and Partition by to get the mindate and max date of dataset.

```
|ResdetId | bookingdate | Amount | AmountExcl |
-----------------------------------------------
|120106   | 2018-02-04  |  75.00 |  70.7547   |
|120106   | 2018-02-05  |  75.00 |  70.7547   |
|120106   | 2018-02-06  |  90.00 |  84.9057   |
|120106   | 2018-02-08  |  75.00 |  70.7547   |
|120106   | 2018-02-09  |  75.00 |  70.7547   |
```

I am using this query

```
select distinct ResDetId, Amount, AmountExcl, 
    min(Bookingdate) OVER(Partition by ResDetId, Amount, AmountExcl) as Mindate,
    max(Bookingdate) OVER(Partition by ResDetId, Amount, AmountExcl) as MaxDate
 from @Cumulatedbookingdetails
```

And I am getting this result

```
|ResdetId | Amount | AmountExcl | MinDate    | MaxDate     |
------------------------------------------------------------
|120106   | 75.00  |  70.7547   | 2018-02-04 |  2018-02-09 |
|120106   | 90.00  |  84.9057   | 2018-02-06 |  2018-02-06 |
```

As we see date 2018-02-07 record is missing from the data set. So, I need result like this

```
|ResdetId | Amount | AmountExcl | MinDate    | MaxDate     |
------------------------------------------------------------
|120106   | 75.00  |  70.7547   | 2018-02-04 |  2018-02-05 |
|120106   | 75.00  |  70.7547   | 2018-02-08 |  2018-02-09 |
|120106   | 90.00  |  84.9057   | 2018-02-06 |  2018-02-06 |
```

Comment: Where is `ReservationDetailId`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: Yeah you did, still there is no `2018-02-07` date and no `ReservationDetailId` column

Comment: Why use `OVER` and `DISTINCT`? `GROUP BY` would be far easier here.

Comment: When you want to group "adjacent" rows (for whatever *your* definition of adjacent is) and report the groups so formed, it's usually referred to as `islands and gaps`. Searching on that should find you plenty of examples.

Comment: @Sami, I edited the question. And 2018-02-07 is intentionally missed. My question is all about how to split the records if the date missing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever,  I am looking into islands and gaps. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach an "Islands and Gaps" problem, such as this, is to use a recursive CTE to build up the islands. We make the non-recursive portion (above the `union`) find the row which marks the start of each island, and the recursive part grows each island one match at a time.

The final results of the CTE unfortunately contain all of the intermediate rows used in building the islands, so you need a final `GROUP` by to select the final island out:

```
declare @t table (ResdetId int, bookingdate date, Amount decimal(9,3), AmountExcl decimal (9,3))
insert into @t(ResdetId,bookingdate,Amount,AmountExcl) values
(120106,'20180204',75.00,70.7547),
(120106,'20180205',75.00,70.7547),
(120106,'20180206',90.00,84.9057),
(120106,'20180208',75.00,70.7547),
(120106,'20180209',75.00,70.7547)

;With Islands as (
    select ResdetId, Amount, AmountExcl,bookingdate as MinDate,bookingDate as MaxDate
    from @t t
    where not exists (select * from @t t2
        where t2.ResdetId = t.ResdetId
        and t2.Amount = t.Amount
        and t2.AmountExcl = t.AmountExcl
        and t2.bookingdate = DATEADD(day,-1,t.BookingDate))
    union all
    select i.ResdetId, i.Amount,i.AmountExcl,i.MinDate,t.bookingDate
    from Islands i
        inner join
        @t t
        on t.ResdetId = i.ResdetId
        and t.Amount = i.Amount
        and t.AmountExcl = i.AmountExcl
        and t.bookingdate = DATEADD(day,1,i.MaxDate)
)
select
    ResdetId, Amount, AmountExcl,MinDate,MAX(MaxDate) as MaxDate
from
    Islands
group by ResdetId, Amount, AmountExcl,MinDate
```

Results:

```
ResdetId    Amount    AmountExcl   MinDate    MaxDate
----------- --------- ------------ ---------- ----------
120106      75.000    70.755       2018-02-04 2018-02-05
120106      75.000    70.755       2018-02-08 2018-02-09
120106      90.000    84.906       2018-02-06 2018-02-06
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't see 2018-02-07 because the bookingdate is not in your Partition so

```
|ResdetId | Amount | AmountExcl 
--------------------------------
|120106   | 75.00  |  70.7547   
|120106   | 90.00  |  84.9057
```

are unique by your Partition. So it is like a Key. You need another attribute to differentiate the same data:

```
|ResdetId | Amount | AmountExcl 
--------------------------------
|120106   | 75.00  |  70.7547
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier to do with `GROUP BY`. `OVER` and `DISTINCT` are much "harder" ways to do the same query:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT ResdetId,
           CONVERT(date,bookingdate) AS bookingdate,
           Amount,
           AmountExcl
    FROM (VALUES (120106,'20180204',75.00,70.7547),
                 (120106,'20180205',75.00,70.7547),
                 (120106,'20180206',90.00,84.9057),
                 (120106,'20180208',75.00,70.7547),
                 (120106,'20180209',75.00,70.7547)) V(ResdetId,bookingdate,Amount,AmountExcl))
SELECT ResdetId,Amount,AmountExcl,
       MIN(bookingdate) AS MinBookingDate,
       MAX(bookingdate) AS MaxBookingDate
FROM VTE
GROUP BY ResdetId,Amount,AmountExcl;
```

As noted my Sami, I had read the results the wrong way round, this is a Gaps and Island question:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT ResdetId,
           CONVERT(date,bookingdate) AS bookingdate,
           Amount,
           AmountExcl
    FROM (VALUES (120106,'20180204',75.00,70.7547),
                 (120106,'20180205',75.00,70.7547),
                 (120106,'20180206',90.00,84.9057),
                 (120106,'20180208',75.00,70.7547),
                 (120106,'20180209',75.00,70.7547)) V(ResdetId,bookingdate,Amount,AmountExcl)),
Grps AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResdetId ORDER BY V.bookingdate) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResdetId, Amount ORDER BY V.bookingdate) AS Grp
    FROM VTE V)
SELECT ResdetId,
       Amount,
       AmountExcl,
       MIN(bookingdate) AS MinBookingDate,
       MAX(bookingdate) AS MaxBookingDate
FROM Grps
GROUP BY ResdetId,
         Amount,
         AmountExcl,
         Grp
ORDER BY ResdetId,
         Amount,
         MinBookingDate;
```

Comment: Does this return the expected results as the OP posted in his question?

Comment: @Sami good point, I had read the expected and result the wrong way round (my first coffee of the day ahas only just arrived!). This actually looks like a gaps and islands issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses row numbers differnce technique:

```
declare @tbl table(ResdetId int, bookingdate date, Amount float, AmountExcl float);
insert into @tbl values
(120106   , '2018-02-04'  ,  75.00 ,  70.7547   ),
(120106   , '2018-02-05'  ,  75.00 ,  70.7547   ),
(120106   , '2018-02-06'  ,  90.00 ,  84.9057   ),
(120106   , '2018-02-08'  ,  75.00 ,  70.7547   ),
(120106   , '2018-02-09'  ,  75.00 ,  70.7547   );

select MIN(bookingDate), MAX(bookingDate), Amount, AmountExcl
from (
    select *,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (order by bookingDate) -
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by amount, AmountExcl order by bookingDate) rn
    from @tbl
) a group by Amount, AmountExcl, rn
```

Comment: Michal, thanks for the answer. I tried your solution too. But its failing for few scenarios.